# Ruby TCP server basics

Tags: ruby, sockets, tcpserver

Can someone explain to me what each part of this code is doing?
It would be helpful if someone could give me a step by step explanation.
Also, how could I upload files?
How do I manipulate a ruby server in general?

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require 'socket'
require 'cgi'

server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 8888)
puts 'Listening on 127.0.0.1:8888'

loop {
  client = server.accept

  first_request_header = client.gets
  resp = first_request_header

  headers = ['http/1.1 200 ok',
             "date: #{CGI.rfc1123_date(Time.now)}",
             'server: ruby',
             'content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
            "content-length: #{resp.length}\r\n\r\n"].join("\r\n")
  client.puts headers          # send the time to the client
  client.puts resp
  client.close
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#required gems
require 'socket'
require 'cgi'

#creating new connection to a local host on port 8888
server = TCPServer.new('127.0.0.1', 8888)
puts 'Listening on 127.0.0.1:8888'

loop {
  #looks like a client method call to open the connection
  client = server.accept
  first_request_header = client.gets
  resp = first_request_header

  #setting the request headers
  headers = ['http/1.1 200 ok',
             "date: #{CGI.rfc1123_date(Time.now)}",
             'server: ruby',
             'content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1',
            "content-length: #{resp.length}\r\n\r\n"].join("\r\n")

  #inserts custom client headers into request
  client.puts headers         
  client.puts resp

  #closes client connection to local host
  client.close
}
```

Comment: what is client.gets doing? What are request headers and why would you need to set them? What does inserting a header into a request mean?

Comment: Here is what `.gets` does: http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/socket/rdoc/Socket.html

Comment: also why does the output to the server seem to get cut off after 30 characters